# How could I use sed to convert a js file with storedVars to a ruby file with methods?

Tags: sed

I have lines like:

```
storedVars["css_delete_driver"] = "css=.driver:nth-child(2) *[data-method=delete]";
storedVars["css_delete_driver2_mobile"] = "css=a.remove-driver";
```

and I want to create a file with methods such as:

```
def css_delete_vehicle_everquote
  "css=.autos .auto *[data-method=delete]"
end
def css_delete_driver
  "css=.driver:nth-child(2) *[data-method=delete]"
end
```

how could I do that with sed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A version that will work with `s/` per line and no in-line returns might be:

```
cat Variables/user-extensions.js | sed $'
s/storedVars/def /
s/\["//
s/"\]//
s/= /\\\n  /
s/;/\\\nend/
'
```

because `$'string'` changes `\\\n` to newlines as detailed in  https://stackoverflow.com/a/18410122/631619

Comment: This version also makes the 2 space indent for ruby clearer

Answer (score 0):

The following sed will do that:

```
cat user-extensions.js | sed '
s/storedVars/def /
s/\["//
s/"\]//
s/=/\
/
s/;/ \
end/
'
```

Comment: Though I would like a version without the actual newlines, i.e. 1 s per line